# Print Preview in Chrome gives changes div positions with CSS style "overflow:hidden"

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have made a jsFiddle of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/g94xyhbn/1/

When I open the print preview with Chrome (press the Print button) and choose the landscape orientation, the result is that the lower boxes seem to disappear. In my CSS, under the media print section for the #outsideDiv element, if I comment the *overflow: hidden* line like this,

```
@media print
{
    #printButton
    {
        display:none;
    }
    #outsideDiv
    {
        left:0px;
        top:50px;
        /*overflow:hidden;*/
        height:900px;
    }
}
```

everything goes back to normal. I use Chrome Version 38.0.2125.122 m. Also, in portrait mode, the print preview displays fine.

What does hiding the overflow has to do with the boxes disappearing? I don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what it's saying it does.

Because you have a defined `height` and `width` on `#outsideDiv`, your CSS is hiding everything that falls outside of that.  Keep in mind that pixels do not convert at the same ratio from screen to page. A page is `72 PPI` (pixel-per-inch) in general, while a printed page is `300 DPI` (dot-per-inch) in general.  There's even a conversion of units there (`pixel` to `dot`) as the medium is so fundamentally different.

Due to that, a better unit to use for `#outsideDiv`'s size would be either `in` or `cm` depending on which unit you're more comfortable using.

As long as the `overflow` is set to `hidden`, however, nothing will display outside the bounds of the box.

Alternatively, you could explicitly override the `height` and `width` rules in your `print` media query.  That would simply tell the div to expand to the size of its contents.  No real difference in your isolated use-case that was presented in the fiddle, but in the event that there are elements around the one being printed, it would cause `#outsideDiv` to properly reserve space for itself in the DOM flow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it does not explain why we do not see the problem in portrait mode. Also, if I change the media query for #outsideDiv height like this: height: 600px; then in the print preview the bottom of the image clearly cuts through the bottom row of boxes without hiding them. Why does it do it when the height is set at 900px, and only in landscape mode?

Comment: 1) I don't know how your print preview looks fine, because mine is very clearly chopped at half the page.

2) You're changing the size of the viewport.  Of course it's going to display differently.  Think about switching between portrait and landscape on a mobile.